# How to merge array by value

Tags: php

I can generate array from mysql, if there is a way for making it easy. I get rows and currently I am rendering like that, if there is a way to generate on fly

3,  0.4311 |
3,  0.1803 |
4,  0.1149 |
4,  0.0775 |
5,  0.4291 |
5,  0.5100|

Considering this array, how to merge it :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [channel_id] => 3
            [value] => 0.4311
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [channel_id] => 3
            [value] => 0.1803
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [channel_id] => 4
            [value] => 0.1149
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [channel_id] => 4
            [value] => 0.0775
        )

 ...
)
```

so it will look like this this:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [channel_id] => 3
                [value] => 0.4311
                [value] => 0.1803
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [channel_id] => 4
                [value] => 0.1149
                [value] => 0.0775

            )
   )
```

Here is the code that I generate this array:

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $array[] = array('channel_id'=>$row['channel_id'],'value'=>$row['value'] );
     }
```

Comment: You can't. Arrays keys have to be unique.

Comment: One problem I see with your end result is that you have the same key `value` set twice for each associative array, that won't work. You probably want another array called `values` holding each `value` (as a separate item) when you merge.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Is possible to add $i so I get [value$i].

Comment: @Turnerj that will work too, if you could point me to that direction

Comment: What does your code look like so far to create this array? (Don't post it as a comment, edit it into your question).

Answer (score 0):

OK this seem impossible, but this is closed I could get:

```
$channels_byid = array();
foreach($array as $v){
    @$channel = $channels_byid[$v['channel_id']];
    if ($array){
         if(!is_array($channel[0])){
             unset($channels_byid[$v['channel_id']]);
             $channels_byid[$v['channel_id']] = $channel;
         }
         $channels_byid[$v['channel_id']][] = $v;
    } else {
        $channels_byid[$v['channel_id']] = $v;
    }
} 
print_r($channels_byid);
```

Which outputs:

```
 [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [channel_id] => 3
                    [value] => 0.7513
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [channel_id] => 3
                    [value] => 0.7234
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [channel_id] => 4
                    [value] => 0.9798
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [channel_id] => 4
                    [value] => 0.7625
                )

        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you were after, but it might be useful. The `channel_id` becomes the top-level key and `value` becomes the values of a new array.

```
$data[] = array('channel_id' => 3, 'value' => 0.4311);
$data[] = array('channel_id' => 3, 'value' => 0.1803);
$data[] = array('channel_id' => 4, 'value' => 0.1149);
$data[] = array('channel_id' => 4, 'value' => 0.0775);

foreach($data as $k => $v) {
    $merge[$v['channel_id']][] = $v['value'];
}
```

And the result of `$merge` is:

```
array(2) {
  [3]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> float(0.4311)
        [1]=> float(0.1803)
  }
  [4]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> float(0.1149)
        [1]=> float(0.0775)
  }
}
```